# Where should people give feedback on Ubuntu?

Tags: community

Many people have opinions or want to give feedback about Ubuntu.  If they are simple bugs with a crash or display corruption, that's fine, they can [file in Launchpad](http://pad.lv/fb/unity).

But, comments about the design or concept of the system are more problematic.  They come up all over the place, such as "https://askubuntu.com/questions/64887/some-unity-feedback" in other places that are not really about Unity.

Ideally the answer will be a place where the comments

- will actually be read by the design team
- will tend to encourage people to read the existing comments and not post the same thing again and again
- perhaps will tend to bubble up good solutions rather than strange ideas
- will not be annoying to people who are trying to use that place for something else

Comment: If its about unity feedback - check this link http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/the-unity-design-process-and-how-you-can-play-a-part-in-it/ - Check the below answers as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of 2020, the best place to give general feedback is in https://discourse.ubuntu.com/.

Comment: Both the ayatana list links are not working :(

Comment: @mac it was renamed; now fixed.

Comment: Thanks. I shall try that. There should be a design list in askUbuntu as well ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It all depends what kind of bugs you found.

Here are a few possible problems you can run into and these are the packages against which you can open a bug

- Dash, Panel, HUD, Expo, Launcher issues --- [unity](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity), [compiz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz)
- Kernel specific thing -- [Linux](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux)
- If you get errrors when running application, then you should log bugs against [glib](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/glib2.0) if the error messages show something like glib, gio, peas. The bug triagers will assign them to correct ones

If you want to discuss something related to desktop related functionality like System Settings, Applications inclusion etc, then send a mail to `ubuntu-desktop@lists.ubuntu.com`

If you want to help out in QA related regression testing, then as you mentioned `ubuntu-qa@lists.ubuntu.com` is the best place.

I would recommend against spending time on brainstorm. There are better ways to provide user feedback.

If your question is related to foundations of ubuntu like udisk, glib etc, then it is better to post it on `ubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 3):

Best Place to improve Ubuntu:

**brainstorm.ubuntu.com**.

Suggest your ideas and ways to improve..

You can also join Ubuntu Team at launchpad also:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise

Comment: I guess brainstorm.ubuntu.com is a better option, But can I submit this minor features as well there?

Comment: Yes submit this feature there. If it gets high votes then there is high chance that this feature will implemented or improved..

Comment: Brainstorm's generally a good idea, but http://askubuntu.com/a/124369/1116 says Unity suggestions there are being closed in favor of the design lists.  I think Ubuntu Forums are not read much by the designers (contradictions welcome.)

Comment: [brainstorm.ubuntu.com is now dead](http://askubuntu.com/q/321289/1116).

Answer (score 3):

Just got a reply from Brainstorm team (I submitted some feedback regarding Unity design)

"Unity has an active, ongoing process of designing improvements. You can participate directly in the Unity design process - Unity welcomes lots of different types of participation.

A very good explanation of how to get involved is at http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/the-unity-design-process-and-how-you-can-play-a-part-in-it/ .

Since Unity discusses such improvements internally among participants instead of through Brainstorm, I'm closing this idea in Brainstorm. "

Answer (score 2):

If you have some programming skills then you can help in fixing bug at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu).
You can also help translate ubuntu in your language at launchpad.