# What is the correct way of proposing design changes to Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should people give feedback on Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-unity)

I recently decided to give Unity another try after moving to gnome shell for the past cycle. I have had a simple idea which I think would greatly improve Unity's multitasking ability just by changing the way icons are ordered on the Launcher.

What is the best way to propose the idea to someone who may have some influence on the actual design of Unity? I posted on brainstorm but the mod said i would be better off "getting involved" in the design process. I dont really have the time for that.