# Is there a lens with scale effect and workspaces switcher?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What lenses for Unity are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38772/what-lenses-for-unity-are-available)

I'm looking for a lens that show the running windows and the other workspaces. Does it exisist? With this feature Unity can be like gnome-shell, I mean "one key to go": I press Super and I have all what I need.

Comment: is super + w not what you want?

Comment: I would like the super+w effect in a lens. Is that possible?

Comment: perhaps I'm not understanding the question - I can't quite see how a lens will improve matters.  Are you after a one key solution (a keyboard shortcut) that does the same as super + w ?

Comment: I would like to have something like gnome-shell. You press super and you have a lens that show you the running apps (and also the workspaces, if possible)

Comment: Why dont your just remap your kb shortcuts to do the same as <super>+w?

Comment: Could be a good idea, but with that I can't have the dash. My idea is scale effect and workspaces switcher inside the dash! Maybe it's not possible...

Comment: I dont think Ask Ubuntu is the place for this, have a look at this question / answer for further advice on what to do next: http://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-unity

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such thing, and that wouldn't be possible the way lenses work now.

I also don't really see why you would want to run it inside a lens. Think it would be better to simply add scale and workspace switcher to the corners and use them as they are, or use buttons on the launcher or something. That should be possible now, though you'd have to use less user friendly tools to configure it.