# Best place to request Ubuntu for a minor improvement (In Unity dash search)

Tags: unity, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should people give feedback on Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-unity)

Which is the best place to request Ubuntu for a minor improvement?

My request feature is this : 
In Ubuntu dash when I search for "Upd" it gives me update manager and some other files. Now when I click enter by default the first entry will be selected. Can we make this a slightly better experience by highlighting the first item in search results which will be selected by default if we press enter - Just like in Gnome shell

Search for upd in unity dash

[image]

Search for upd in gnome-shell

[image]

If you notice, update manager is highlighted by default in gnome shell and appears more intuitive. Can we implement the same in Unity ?

Sorry for posting this in askubuntu. I just wanted to know which is the best place to discuss this. Thanks