# What's the most appropriate ubuntu list for feeding back on user issues?

Tags: installation, upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should people give feedback on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-ubuntu)

Background: I'm a retired computer guy, have played with Linux since 1993, been out of the loop for awhile, but recently re-committed to Ubuntu and am looking to get involved a bit in its development and growth.

I just upgraded to 12.04 beta2 and have identified a few... glitches and issues in the process, from a simple end-user perspective. There seems to more than one list that might fit, in the Ubuntu-devel- or perhaps Ubuntu-qa- or even Ubuntu-desktop- hierarchies.  (I've also found places like Brainstorm and BugSquad.)

Comments and suggestions? :)

Cheers,
Alec.