# Where can I give feedback to Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

I am an end-user of Kubuntu and I wish to give feedback for it. What is the best source for that?

Comment: Similar question (http://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-ubuntu)  - in many ways you can subsitute kubuntu for ubuntu in the various suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...and more:

**Feedback**

Every Kubuntu release has a feedback page - the latest:
http://www.kubuntu.org/ --> http://www.kubuntu.org/news/12.04-release

> Feedback
>
> We want to hear your opinions about Kubuntu 12.04 LTS  Do we [Ama]rok?
>   Did a feature make or break your day?  What do you flat-out dislike?
>
> Take a look at the Ubuntu Code of Conduct, try Kubuntu 12.04 LTS and
>   head on over to the Feedback Page. Your input is an invaluable
>   resource, so do take the time to write down your thoughts and let us
>   know what you think.

**Ideas**

The Kubuntu Forums has:
http://www.kubuntuforums.net/content.php --> http://www.kubuntuforums.net/forumdisplay.php?165-Round-Table-Discussions-Moderated

> Round Table Discussions - Moderated
>
> Ideas for Kubuntu improvements? Post and discuss them here with a
>   Council member.