# How to give feedback to the Ubuntu developers

Tags: launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best medium for sending feature requests?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/what-is-the-best-medium-for-sending-feature-requests)
>   [Where should people give feedback on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-ubuntu)

I am pretty annoyed that I can't move the Unity launcher in Ubuntu 12.04. I know there are alternatives as in using a different desktop, but I think users who don't know how to install these, or don't want to learn, or don't want to fiddle with what should be a robust, user friendly interface out of the box, should have the option to move the launcher to their liking. I want to pass this feedback on to the developers. What is the best way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways:

1. Join the Ubuntu-devel list, and submit your idea:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel

2. Go to Brainstorm and submit it there

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/

3. Go to the website of the application itself and file a feature request

If it's a bug report, submit it in Launchpad:

https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/NewAccount

Before submitting a bug you should read

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs/

This as already beem discused in [AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/what-is-the-best-medium-for-sending-feature-requests)

Comment: Thanks for that, I realise now that I can't be bothered. From all I have learnt reading other threads, it seems the developers have given up on the open source spirit and decided they know best and won't allow their users to have any choice in the matter. I can't be bothered any more trying to influence such pig-headedness and will just use kubuntu desktop, or Gnome classic or something.