# Is there somewhere to voice an opinion on the default maximise, minimise, close button location

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should people give feedback on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-ubuntu)

I've been looking for somewhere to give proper feedback on the UI, specifically the side of the window the maximize, minimize and close buttons are on by default, for Unity and I simply can't find one.

Is this something that doesn't actually exist because that part of Unity is not open to discussion?