# How to iconize all windows for current application, Unity

Tags: unity, docky, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should people give feedback on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100963/where-should-people-give-feedback-on-ubuntu)

I am used to Docky, and miss the ability to easily iconize/hide all windows for a given application, or to see a list of the window titles for each window for a given application.

Double clicking the icon in Unity shows all of the current windows as a means to select one of them, but a simple list of window titles when you hover the pointer over the icon would often be preferable when you are thinking of the name of the document you want to show.

Is there a better way to iconize all the windows for a current application than having to click on each of their iconize buttons on their window bars? In Docky, you can show or hide the windows by clicking the application icon on the icon bar.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this was already brought up.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/733349

You can click on the "This bug affects me" part at the top, possibly popular opinion can have some impact.

[image]

There is much discussion and even someone that made a fix. [https://code.launchpad.net/~ojno/unity/minimize-on-click](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eojno/unity/minimize-on-click)

You may be able use his PPA to try it out [https://launchpad.net/~ojno/+archive/unity-minimize-on-click](https://launchpad.net/%7Eojno/+archive/unity-minimize-on-click)

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

---

As the feature was rejected and even commented on by SABDFL - (Mark Shuttleworth)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/733349/comments/19

> Mark Shuttleworth (sabdfl) wrote on 2011-04-21: Re: [Bug 733349] Re:
> Add 'minimize all windows' option to the quicklist of running
> applications  #19
>
> Rocko, no, clicking on the icon will not minimise the app.
>
> We have a minimise button for that, it's prominent.
>
> status opinion
>
> Mark

It is currently **Won't Fix** status.