# Ubuntu Brainstorm site down/dead?

Tags: community, brainstorm

is http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com dead?
I get redirected to http://community.ubuntu.com/ ?
other references are dead as well. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Brainstorm/

This mailing list suggest the closure in May 2013:
 https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-May/037100.html

But I couldn't find any official note. Please enlighten me :-)

Comment: here a brief new article from Heise: http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Ubuntu-to-stop-Brainstorm-1862298.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ubuntu Brainstorm was indeed shutdown/sunsetted. The data will be available to the community as soon as it's anonymized. There hasn't really been an announcement after that post.

I talked about Brainstorm a bit in this interview:

- https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-48

(Fast forward to 12:30 if you just want to listen to the part about Brainstorm).

Comment: So what is the alternative now? http://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/what-is-the-best-medium-for-sending-feature-requests

Answer (score 2):

The current place for feature requests and feedback is [discourse.ubuntu.com](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/).

> Welcome to the Ubuntu Community Discourse, a site for co-ordination of the Ubuntu project.
>
> This community resource is for people working at all levels of the stack on Ubuntu. We welcome discussion of Ubuntu itself and other closely related topics. We welcome your [site feedback](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/site-feedback).
>
> This site is not for technical support.

Comment: Folks should keep in mind that discourse.ubuntu.com is primarily a collaboration site for community contributors (code, testing, documentation, translation, local groups, community events, etc). It's not a great place to share strong opinions...unless you're a contributor, and the opinion is about contributions.