# where to submit feature ideas when brainstorm.ubuntu. is dead

Tags: community, brainstorm

I had an idea/feature suggest to make for Ubuntu. But, as I found out, the site is dead. See: [Ubuntu Brainstorm site down/dead?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321289/ubuntu-brainstorm-site-down-dead).

**Question**: Where can i make a feature suggest/idea now that brainstorm.ubuntu is no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make a feature suggest at launchpad as a wishlist bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

You can also suggest feature and ideas at https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-discuss

Comment: Thanks, am assuming here that the `wishlist bug` button, is in actuality the `Ask a question` button. right?

Comment: No: Its report a bug. The bug is "This feature needs to be added to this package".  Mark the bug with the "Wishlist" tag and the developers will know there is a demand.  These types of bugs unfortunately are not usually given a high priority so you may have more luck trying to approach the upstream developers.

Comment: How can you actually file the bug on the launchpad page? I click on "Report a bug" in the top right corner, which leads to a page, where there is no possibility to file a bug

Comment: It seems like this is only possible now at the console if you type `ubuntu-bug`