# I have ideas for apps for Ubuntu.

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

How do I submit ideas for apps? I am not a programmer

Comment: ***Be encouraged ..*** Software is about *abstraction*, or separating the idea from the implementation. Different people have the skills to answer: *What do we want to achieve? What is the (real world) purpose? What features will make it cool / useful? What should it look like? What development tools / code libraries / icons / etc. should be used? ETC.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to become a developer we have some great resources for people of all skill levels here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/

And while it's not currently being used, we have a sub-reddit where people have suggested ideas of apps during our app development contests, which we will be running again this year, so you can post your ideas there and maybe somebody will take them up: http://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntuappshowdown/

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28440/what-is-the-best-medium-for-sending-feature-requests). There used to be a site called [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) for that, but that was closed early last year. <sub>See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321289/ubuntu-brainstorm-site-down-dead)</sub>

You could [become a developer though](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/developers/).

Answer (score 0):

Good to hear you are interested in developing Ubuntu. 
If you have no programming skills yourself, my suggestion would be to get on one of the the IRC channel for Ubuntu developers and pitch your idea. My feeling is that currently, the most active developers are on #ubuntu-touch on freenode because gradualy, development in Qt/QML will be the standard for all Ubuntu (although many others are possible).
And even though you are not a programmer, you could still do many usefull things once a project gets started.

gd luck